# PHP regex to match all single letters followed by numeric value in string

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match, letter

I'm trying to get the a regex running for the following type of strings: one upper case letter followed by a numeric value. The string can consist of multiple of these letter-numeric-value combinations. Here some examples and my expected output:

```
A12B8Y9CC10
-> output [0 => 12, 1 => 8, 2 => 9] (10 is ignored, because there are two letters)
V5C8I17
-> output [0 => 5, 1 => 8, 2 => 17]
KK18II9
-> output [] (because KK and II are always two letters followed by numeric values)
I8VV22ZZ4S9U2
-> output [0 => 8, 1 => 9, 2 => 2] (VV and ZZ are ignored)
A18Z12I
-> output [0 => 18, 1 => 12] (I is ignored, because no numeric value follows)
```

I tried to reach this by the following regex using preg_match:
/^([A-Z]{1}\d{1,)$/

But it doesn't give the expected output. Can you please help me, how to solve this?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in `php` using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]\K\d+/', $string, $matches);
```

Resulting in array `$matches[0]` to return all the matches.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0rh8HB/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])`: Make sure we don't have a letter before current position
- `[a-zA-Z]`: Match a letter
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava! Works great. Only the left bracket is missing in the code you posted. Must look like that: preg_match_all('/(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]\K\d+/', $string, $matches);
Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 3):

Another variant could be using [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip matches that do not qualify.

```
[A-Z]{2,}\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[A-Z](\d+)
```

*Explanation*

- `[A-Z]{2,}\d+` Match 2 or more uppercase chars A-Z and 1+ digits
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Use SKIP FAIL to avoid matching
- `|` Or
- `[A-Z](\d+)` Match a single char A-Z and capture in **group 1** one or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuYfBV/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/KJpJA)

The matches are the first capturing group.

```
$pattern = '/[A-Z]{2,}\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[A-Z](\d+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

---

Or with the `\K` as in anubhava's answer

```
[A-Z]{2,}\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[A-Z]\K\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGc74s/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/WmeeV)